# Why hasn’t SpiceJet painted their own logo on their newly acquired aircraft?

Tags: airlines, livery

So I’m referring to the airline company SpiceJet here. They have acquired old airplanes of the company that has now gone under, Jet Airways. [image]

The above plane is clearly an old Jet-Lite plane that SpiceJet acquired, my question is why don’t they paint the fin or even the body with SpiceJet colors and logo?

Is it not economical or just not worth anything to the company to do so?

Comment: Painting an aircraft is expensive, not just materials and labor but downtime. Low cost carriers operate on very low margins, they may not have the budget until it's down for other reasons like a check.

Comment: Also, given that the photo is from FlightRadar24 - a private company, not a government or licencing body - there is no guarantee that the photo is up-to-date.

Comment: Well, I also saw the plane directly overhead and it wasn’t painted. Haha.